# why variable++ is not working the same way as variable+1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is one of the most basic things in React but I wonder why `counter+1` is working, but in `counter++` you must double click to increase the number?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const counterHandler = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {counter}
      <button onClick={counterHandler}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `++counter` would have worked. `counter++` is equivalent with returning old counter value, and then incrementing the variable. Clicking twice would be buggy.

Comment: @callmenikk why? state is not mutable by nature , I'm just changing it by setCounter , what I can I do Instead ?

Comment: oh my bad, I had to say never use `let` or `var` on useState()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let x = 3
let y = x++
//output: x=4 y=3

let x = 3
let y = ++x
//output: x=4 y=4
```

It's why you need to double click because you have next logic:

```
console.log(counter) //0
//triggers click
console.log(counter) //0, useState re-assigned to 0
//triggers click 
console.log(counter) //1, useState re-assigned to 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Difference is that `counter + 1` is only an operation and `counter++` is an operation with an assignment. In React you shouldn't assign your state directly but use the setter method. So in your case it is better to use `counter + 1`